# typescript repeating T extend X can be cumbersome, is they're a better way?

Tags: typescript, boilerplate

Is they're a way in typecript to avoir repeating `T extends ISomething<T>` all over. If i have an interface as such:

```
interface ISomething<T> {
  avalue: T
  // ...
}
```

Whenever I want to ensure a parameter of a function is of that type i have to write:

```
const afunction = <T extends ISomething<T>>(aparam: T) => {
  // do something
}
```

If i've got another function using a parameter that needs to be of the same type, i have to repeat the syntax

```
const bfunction = <T extends ISomething<T>>(aparam: T) => {
  // do something
}
```

When in a file or in a set of file i do have a lot of function (i do not like classes jéjéjé^^) that do need the same type it makes a lot of boilerplate.

What i'm searching for would be a shorthand of somekind to be able to write something like

```
// type TI<T> = T extends ISomething<T>
```

end then be able to:

```
const cfunction = <TI<T>>(aparam: T) => {
  // do something
}
```

or even better

```
const cfunction = <TI>(aparam: TI) => {
  // do something
}
```

**Is they're such a type definition that exists?**

I've looked a lot in the documentation and didn't found anything :/

It provides as much information regarding the typing used and make *a lot less code* to write especially when the numbers of function starts to adds up.

Thanks in advance for your reading  and hopefully they're is a better way hoho ^^

Seb

Comment: Nope, that is the syntax, no shorter form. You can obly define a type alias for a type. When you introduce a new generic type parameter to a function you need to use the `extends` keyoword followed by a type

Comment: It's a shame :/ Why not allow aliases as such? it will make code much cleaner while providing as much information regarding typings. Is they're is a reason for it ?  I like a lot typescript, but when typing start to be messy, it can takes so much space that it makes the code quiet hard te read. The declaration regarding arguments are fine, as you can write an argument per line but the declaration surrounding the function (generic and returns type) can get pretty ugly and quiet hard to read. If it can be computed before execution and helps render the code cleaner why not put it in place?

Comment: This wouldn't make much sense, you have to write extends. You might want to remove type parameter in a type you always extend.

Comment: Hello ;), could you provide more explanation to this point: "You might want to remove type parameter in a type you always extend" ? not sure I get it.  Also the sense of the idea is not to add meaning as the meaning is in the type, but to add clarity in the code by shrinking redundant uses typings. Information will still be available by looking at the alias - we loose no typings information while making cleaner code